# Is it possible to add triggers (like the ones used in snippets) for quickly citing specific terms my text (LaTex, Overleaf)?

Tags: nomenclature, auto-completion, code-snippets

I am writing a paper that includes hundreds of species names, authors and years (e.g., Homo sapiens Linnaeus, 1758). It is very hard to keep track of all these details and fairly easy to accumulate mistakes. So, I was thinking to add an additional file (e.g., .tex) that includes the list of the species that I'm going to mention in the manuscript. Maybe `glossaries`, `acronyms` and perhaps `nomenclature` packages may be used for this purpose. However, as far as I know, none of them allow to generate triggers (like the ones used in snippets and auto-completion) to easily pick up the species names from the list. Is there any way to implement such a feature in one of these packages? Alternatively, is there any other package you can suggest me? Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! I think your issue is less related to a package and more your system and editor you are using, I am not aware of any LaTeX package that offers auto-completion as those packages typically only apply upon running the file

Comment: @JamesT: thanks for your reply. Now I found a solution to my problem - at least a preliminary one :) the glossaries-extra + bib2gls combination works super fine for my purposes! although with some small issues. I'm going to make a new post with additional questions. Thanks again