# Triggers and auto-completions with ```glossaries-extra``` + ```bib2gls``` in Latex Workshop and Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, auto-completion, glossaries-extra, latex-workshop, bib2gls

I've recently raised a question about citing and keeping track of long lists of species names ([Is it possible to add triggers (like the ones used in snippets) for quickly citing specific terms my text (LaTex, Overleaf)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/683690/is-it-possible-to-add-triggers-like-the-ones-used-in-snippets-for-quickly-citi)). Just to keep you updated (in case somebody else out there was looking for some solutions), the combination of  `glossaries-extra` and `bib2gls` works excellently for me.
This is basically what I was looking for: one or more .bib files to store my entries (i.e., hundreds of species names + authors + publication years) and the possibility to recall them in my "main" file using simple arguments (i.e., `\gls`).
Basically, I could make it working in LaTex Workshop (LW), and partly in Overleaf (OL) thank to OL team (actually, the latter is the LaTex editor that we normally use within our research group to write papers). However, in both cases I found some minor issues, and probably some of you can give me some solutions:

1. LW: auto-completion is triggered only the second time that I cite a specific term included in my "entries.bib" (the file with glossary terms). And this works only with the command `\gls*` (auto-completion doesn't work with the simple `\gls`). Is this normal?
2. OV: `bib2gls` only works if triggered in an additional "latekmkrc" file. However auto-completion doesn't work, neither with `\gls*` nor `\gls`. Any idea why? Is this due to the `bib2gls` version? If so, can I upgrade it just indicating the version in the latekmkrc file? Otherwise, is there any other solution to overcome this issue?

Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Auto-completions like this are editor-specific functionalities, there's probably little we can do to help here. With LaTeX Workshop it sounds somewhat like you have found a bug (in which case report it to the plugin) if auto-completion works for `\gls*` but not `\gls`. With Overleaf this likely isn't supported (I don't believe there are any options to customise auto-completions) and you would need to make a feature request there.

Comment: @DaiBowen: Thanks a lot for the hints!

Comment: We are trying out an Overleaf Community edition on premises server. I can't seem to get Overleaf to trigger the bib2gls compile step. What are the magic latexmkrc commands to make this happen?

Comment: @LaTeXFan this works for me: $pdflatex = 'pdflatex %O %S; bib2gls %B'; hope it helps